# An error occurred while executing the command definition - WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, wcf, appharbor

I've updated my model and done rebuilding the project (as suggested by stackoverflow) but no benefit.

My ASP.NET wcf webservice is working fine on local host. But when I upload it to AppHarbor (free asp.net web hosting service) I get an exception (I'm calling like this http://pizzaapp.apphb.com/Service1.svc/Login/123/1) which I can't understand (shown below). This works perfectly on my localhost, so what's the problem after uploading?

> Request Error The server encountered an error processing the request.
>   The exception message is 'An error occurred while executing the
>   command definition. See the inner exception for details.'. See server
>   logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:
>
> at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext
>   context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetResults>b__2()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1
>   func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean
>   startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetResults>b__1()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1
>   operation) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1
>   forMergeOption) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
>   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue() at
>   System.Lazy`1.get_Value() at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   sequence) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1
>   query, Expression queryRoot) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression) at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression) at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source) at
>   WcfServicePizza.Service1.Login(String phoneNo, String password) in
>   d:\temp\lmtrshzg.bwx\input\WcfServicePizza\Service1.svc.cs:line 37 at
>   SyncInvokeLogin(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

The code for the webservice interface

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="SignUp",
        Method="POST",
        BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    bool SignUp(Customer customer);
```

And code for its implementation running on the server currently is:

```
    public bool Login(string phoneNo, string password)
    {
        decimal phoneNoDecimal = Decimal.Parse(phoneNo);
        DatabasePizzaEntities db = new DatabasePizzaEntities();
        Customer customer = db.Customers.Where(c => c.PhoneNo==phoneNoDecimal && c.Password == password).SingleOrDefault();
        if (customer == null)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

INNER EXCEPTION:

> Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name
>   'dbo.Customer'.\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1
>   wrapCloseInAction)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean
>   asyncClose)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()\u000d\u000a
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClassb.<Reader>b__8()\u000d\u000a
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TInterceptionContext,TResult](Func`1
>   operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1
>   executing, Action`1 executed)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand
>   command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)\u000d\u000a
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\u000d\u000a   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand
>   entityCommand, CommandBehavior
>   behavior)\u000d\u000aClientConnectionId:2c6eb8fd-ce5b-4866-8dc7-5ff565fb11d5\u000d\u000aError
>   Number:208,State:1,Class:16"

Comment: what is inner exception?

Comment: The error is in the server, not in wcf, do you connect with the same DB in the 2 envirements?

Comment: @ Manish Parakhiya How to see the inner exception?

@ElishevaWasserman I'm only changing the connection string.

Comment: Without knowing the inner exception this question is useless. Look in the server's event log or improve your logging.

Comment: I've added the inner exception. I do have Customer in ADO.net Entity Data model. Then why am I getting this?

Comment: This is a database problem.  where is your database hosted and does AppHarbor have access to it? You should look at your SQL ConnectionStrings.  Perhaps you need a config transform for deployment

Answer (score 1):

The difference between local host and AppHarbor is which database you are connecting to.

The error message is:

```
An error occurred while executing the command definition
```

This is generally a problem between your database schema and your mapping files.

Is the database Schema In AppHarbor different from that in your local database?

This is "Invalid Object Name", either:

- the Customer table is not there,
- or it is not in the dbo schema,
- or the user in the connection string does not have rights to access the table.

Comment: Appharbor uses git and everything I've here in local is uploaded to that server.

Comment: Check the definition of your Customer table, how does what is on your local database compare with the definition in git.

Comment: I've added the inner exception. I do have Customer in ADO.net Entity Data model. Then why am I getting this?